# Error in getting json response from DSS server: "Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm getting following error while requesting json response from my dss service.

```
{"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""}}
```

curl request which i pass is

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:9764/services/userdetails/test
```

I am getting the proper xml response if i remove accept header.

Strange thing is if i am running the same dss service from my colleague's laptop, i m getting the proper json response with that above curl command. Some configuration has changed in my pc because of that i'm getting this error in my pc.

I am not able to find what has changed in my pc because of which i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 6):

I also experienced the same recently. I was hoping to debug and find the cause, but didn't get a chance yet.

However, changing `application/json` formatter and sender implementations in `respository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` resolved the issue. For that, you can uncomment/comment-out followings.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                  class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonFormatter" /-->


<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonBuilder" /-->
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: actually wen i restarted my database and wso2 server the problem got solved automatically...i need not do this change in the configuration...will inform here if i get the error again

Comment: Worked for me with the solution proposed up here